# Background color for one line in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to make one line in tinymce with orange background color. Let's say the text in tinymce has three lines, I want to make the middle one with orange background.

I've searched on the internet for hours and nothing. This seems impossible. As I see in the Inspect Element in Chrome, the lines don't even have a css class.

Comment: I have no experience with tinyMCE but I would just add a span around the text I wanted to have a background color and style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code to style the second paragraph of the editor content:

```
var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
$(ed.getBody()).find('p:first').next().css('background-color', 'red');
```